# Roblox Invalid require

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to help my son with Roblox Studio. I'm an app developer but have never used Roblox before.

I'm stuck being able to call a function from another file...

We have a file called `InsRankHandler` under `ServerScriptService`. It has a `Frame` with some `Labels` and I can change the text in the labels just fine when using the `game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect` callback.

We now want to change the labels text from an `Adonis` function.

I've added a function to the `InsRankHandler` file like this:

```
local InsRankHandler = {}
function InsRankHandler.setText(text)
    local clone = script.Rank:Clone()
    clone.Frame.Name1.Text = text
end
return InsRankHandler
```

Then I try to call it from the `Adonis` function like this:

```
local fun = require(game.ServerScriptService.InsRankHandler)
fun.setText("something");
```

but this gives me an error of an incorrect require.

If I `print` like this:

```
print(game.ServerScriptService.InsRankHandler);
```

it correctly shows `InsRankHandler` so I can't figure out what is wrong. I know it's probably some really obvious syntax error.

EDIT -----

I've added a `ModuleScript` under `ServerScriptService` that contains this:

```
local module = {}

function module.setText(text)
    print("setText:")
end

return module
```

Then in the `Adonis` function (that is also under `ServerScriptService`) I try to access it like this:

```
local fun = require(game.ServerScriptService.module)
```

or like this:

```
local fun2 = require(game.ServerScriptService.ModuleScript.module)
```

but both give me the error: `module is not a valid member of...`

Comment: It correctly shows the handler because it is the handler, no need to further require it :)

Comment: If I try and call it directly like this `game.ServerScriptService.InsRankHandler.setText("test");` I get the error `setText is not a valid member of Script "ServerScriptService.InsRankHandler"`

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, misunderstood that. I read a bit more, and found [shared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055534/how-to-call-functions-in-other-script-files-in-roblox) as a way to share functions but what you want is a [ModuleScript](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/ModuleScript). Maybe not relevant, but did you explicitly created a ModuleScript, e.g. as described here https://create.roblox.com/docs/education/coding-6/intro-to-module-scripts? Maybe it differentiate between Script and ModuleScript.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: how did you name the file? Is it called `module`?

Comment: The file is named `ModuleScript` then inside it I have the module called `module`. It can print `ServerScriptService.ModuleScript` but fails when trying to print `ServerScriptService.ModuleScript.module`. I'm wondering if maybe Adonis just doesn't have access to the modules.

Comment: I've created a brand new empty game. Added `adonis` and dragged it to `ServerScriptService`. Created a `ModuleScript` but the `adonis` function just can't seem to see the module inside the file.